# How do I make HTTP requests inside a loop in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a command line script in Node (because I know JS and suck at Bash + I need jQuery for navigating through DOM)… right now I'm reading an input file and I iterate over each line.

How do I go about making one HTTP request (GET) per line so that I can load the resulting string with jQuery and extract the information I need from each page?
I've tried using the NPM `httpsync` package… so I could make one blocking GET call per line of my input file but it doesn't support HTTPS and of course the service I'm hitting *only* supports HTTPS.

Thanks!

Comment: sorry but why blocking call specially..

Comment: I've kind of changed by mind about blocking… but blocking makes it simple to not create a huge number of requests. I'm potentially loading 1000+ line files and so if I don't block the script will create a huge number of parallel requests, no? Throttling could work but I can't wrap my head around it ATM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was worried about making a million simultaneous requests without putting in some kind of throttling/limiting the number of concurrent connections, but it seems like Node is throttling me "out of the box" to something around 5-6 concurrent connections.

This is perfect, as it lets me keep my code a lot simpler while also fully leveraging the inherent asynchrony of Node.

Comment: It is the [HTTP `Agent`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) that's doing the throttling (controlled by `http.globalAgent.maxSockets`, default `5`), but be warned that in node 0.12, there will be no default limit.

Answer (score 5):

A good way to handle a large number of jobs in a conrolled manner is the [async queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue).

I also recommend you look at [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) for making HTTP requests and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) for dealing with the HTML you get.

Putting these together, you get something like:

```
var q = async.queue(function (task, done) {
    request(task.url, function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        if (res.statusCode != 200) return done(res.statusCode);

        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        // ...
        done();
    });
}, 5);
```

Then add all your URLs to the queue:

```
q.push({ url: 'https://www.example.com/some/url' });
// ...
```

Comment: request and cheerio are exactly what I ended up using, actually :)

Comment: Separately, why is the async queue better than than request + the config you mentioned as a comment to my reply?

Answer (score 1):

I would most likely use the async library's function `eachLimit` function. That will allow you to throttle the number of active connections as well as getting a callback for when all the operations are done.

```
async.eachLimit(urls, function(url, done) {
    request(url, function(err, res, body) {
        // do something
        done();
    });
}, 5, function(err) {
    // do something
    console.log('all done!');
})
```